# IF condition to show drop down when "yes", to give specific cell when "no

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Worksheet picture

[image]
Basically I have 3 sheets, the first one called **Menu** which has the drop down list sources and the entire sheet is hidden. The second one is **Emp** it has the database with list of employees. The third one which has all the formulas called **Sales**.

As you can see in the picture, in the **Sales** sheet's first table there is a column called **[Renewal?]** and inside it is a data validation drop down list which is sourced from the first worksheet **Menu** and has only two options "Yes" or "No".

What I'm looking to do is, if I chose Renewal to "No" then lookup the columns for that specific employee and automatically fill his data. Meaning if we will not renew his contract then his position is empty and should be filled in the table below **Vacancies**. And if it we will renew his contract (in this case "Yes") then show a drop down list of all positions in the department as it will considered as a general opening in the department.

Sorry if I didn't explain thoroughly enough for you, feel free to ask me anything to clarify.

Comment: This question is too broad. You will need to write more than 2 lines of code to get this done with VBA. StackOverflow is not a code writing service it's more for people who have specific issues with code they have written. So you will need to show the code you already have.

Comment: @Peh I don't have much done except for some simple Index/Match formulas to get data from the database, in this example I just took records for employees who are in the Sales department and showed them in this table. Other than that, just a couple data validation drop downs. That's about it.

Comment: Yes, but don't expect that people here are doing all the work for you. As I wrote this is not a free code writing service. People here can point out issues in your code but they usually don't write code for you. This platform is to help people but not to do their work.

Comment: @Peh I'm not looking for someone to do my work, I'm looking for someone who can guide and teach me.

Comment: Then this might be the wrong place. This site is more for people who have already code and have a specific question. StackOverflow is based on a question+answer system and not like a forum where you can guide/teach someone in a discussion. Therefore most times general unspecific questions are closed by the community. I advise you to better look for a forum or something where you can get better guidance and being taught how to start writing a VBA code if you don't get an answer here. You are welcome to come back with any specific question if you have some code written.